# Handle CSV file to txt file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to convert many CSV files(for each CSV file, I just need The first five elements of the first column) into a text file. And here is my code.

import pandas as pd
import os

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data_v6/level3/"):
    count = 1
    for dir in dirs:
        print(dir)
        count= count+1
        print(count)
        df = pd.read_csv('data_v6/level3/'+dir+'/tweets_topic.csv',usecols=[0])
        print(df.loc[0:4])
        #print(df)
        df.to_csv('data_v6/level3/topic_DIC.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

But it can not work. I got this error.

```
File "F:/RUN/RUN/GetDictionary.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(df.loc[0:4])
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 879, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1088, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1122, in _get_slice_axis
    indexer = labels.slice_indexer(
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4966, in slice_indexer
    start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5167, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, "left", kind)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5079, in get_slice_bound
    label = self._maybe_cast_slice_bound(label, side, kind)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5031, in _maybe_cast_slice_bound
    self._invalid_indexer("slice", label)
  File "F:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3267, in _invalid_indexer
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on Index with these indexers [0] of type int
```

Comment: Can you share sample input/output data?

Comment: i think you need to use ```iloc``` instead of ```loc``` for pandas slicing: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a high power hammer drill where a simple screwdriver would be more appropriate. Pandas is indeed a very powerful library that nicely handles csv files with automatic type detection, but you do not need all of that: you only need the 4 first fields of the first column.

Just use the csv module here:

```
with open('data_v6/level3/topic_DIC.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./data_v6/level3/"):
        count = 1
        for dir in dirs:
            print(dir)
            count= count+1
            print(count)
            with open('data_v6/level3/'+dir+'/tweets_topic.csv') as fd:
                rd = csv.reader(fd)
                try:
                    _ = next(rd)             # skip header line
                exception StopIteration:
                    print('data_v6/level3/'+dir+'/tweets_topic.csv is empty')
                    continue
                try:
                    for i in range(4):
                        try:
                            row = next(rd)
                            print(row[0], file=outfile)
                        except StopIteration:
                            break
```

Comment: Thank you, bro. I have tried this code, but it still can not work.

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.

Comment: @Max: this is a syntax error in the full Python script. Double check indentation, quoting and parens...